# Don't allow register user url if it exists in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, web, registration

I'm trying to set up registration on WordPress that doesn't allow user's website to register more times. Simply said - I don't want one user to register many times with the same website. This works with emails and username. If the email is already in use won't allow registration. The same thing but for the users urls. Do you have any suggestion how to set up? Thanks!

I have tried to create a function that checks for url and if it finds it will create an error. But I'm not sure if there are other instances that prevents my set up because it doesn't work. Also I'm using wp-members plugin for registration. The code I was trying to edit was in wp-includes/users.php

```
function user_url_exists( $user_url ) {
if ( $user_url = get_user_by('url', $user_url) ) {
        return $user_url->ID;
} else {
        return null;
}}

if ( !$update && ! defined( 'WP_IMPORTING' ) && user_url_exists($user_url) ) return new WP_Error('existing_user_url', __('This website address is already registered.') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [WangGuard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wangguard/) plugin. :)

Comment: The plugin doesn't have that. :(

Comment: As they say: "WangGuard NOT protect your site from comment spam, WangGuard protect your registration page from sploggers, unwanted users and untrusted users and WangGuard clean your database from them".

It's worthwhile, but I assume you need only that functionality. ;)

Comment: Also other issue is that they require API in order for the plugin to work. Also they limit your business with it and that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks thought for your suggestion, maybe in the future I will consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this must be asked in WP Members forum. Thought you were developing a custom code... :(

http://butlerblog.com/wp-members/

Best!
**R**

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't look like is responding. Can you please direct how to apply this? Thanks,